# Is it OK to throw exceptions defined in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, exception

I was wondering whether or not it is considered OK to throw exceptions that are defined in the C++ standard library, instead of creating my own class. For example, let's consider the following (stupid) function that takes one string as an argument:

```
#include <stdexcept> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool useless_function(const std::string& str) {
    if (str == "true")
        return true;

    else if (str == "false")
        return false;

    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Expected argument of either true or false");
}
```

and then of course, we could do something like:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    try {
        const bool check = useless_function("not true");
    }

    catch (std::invalid_argument& error) {
        std::cerr << error.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) that the `std::stoi` family of functions throw an `std::invalid_exception` exception when they receive an invalid argument; that's where the above idea came from.

Comment: There's an entire header, `<stdexcept>`, with ready-made exception classes for you to use so you *don't* go off inventing your own wheels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to use standard exception classes for your own purposes. If they fit your situation well, go ahead (but don't hesitate to define your own class when/if no standard class fits well).

Also note that you can derive from the standard classes, so if you can add significantly greater precision or new behavior that isn't present in the standard class, you may still want to use it as a base class.

The better question (IMO) would be when it would make sense to define your own exception classes (that don't at least derive from the standard ones). One obvious candidate here would be if you want to support something like a `what()` that returns a string in something like UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoding, so the "stock" "std::exception" wouldn't provide much (if any) utility, and you're pretty much stuck with starting over from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! I was just unsure of whether or not the classes in `<stdexcept>` were intended to be used by non-standard-library code.